# Request get not supported

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I'm  following [this tutorial](https://murygin.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/rest-web-service-file-uploads-spring-boot/#comment-2725) and when I test the code by clicking the upload button, my console log says that my request is not supported.

Also when I debug, I have a problem here's what I have:

[image]

Comment: can you share your code? form and rest service, please?

Comment: you will find them in the tutoriel that i mentioned